# seaborn tsplot with non-connected confidence intervals

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I'm using seaborn's tsplot function to plot how well my model fit matches actual data in a time series, with CIs showing my predictions' standard deviations. My question is: Is there a way for tsplot not to fill in CIs between points? That is, for it to show the CIs of each point individually without connecting one CI to the next.

For the means this is accomplished by setting "interpolate" to False. I'm looking the same -- but for CIs.

To illustrate, my plots currently look like this:

[image: offending tsplot]

I'm fine with how this looks for means (red dots) that are close together, but the CI-transition looks rather odd when one mean is close to 1 and the next is close to 0. The data just happens to be like this. I'd be happy to turn the CI "connection" off, but would also be happy for any related aesthetic suggestions. Thank you.

For completeness' sake, the relevant offending code fragment is as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model_fit = #fit data
data =  #actual data

sns.tsplot(model_fit,interpolate=False,ci='sd',color='indianred',condition='predicted')
plt.plot(X,actual_data ,linestyle='None',marker='*',label='actual')
```

Comment: Looks like your data aren't really appropriate for this function

Comment: That might just be it. Any suggestions for an alternative way to plot SDs as transparent colors surrounding the mean (as in a tsplot) rather than as bars? I dislike the cluttered look of the latter and liked tsplots way of displaying them.

Comment: Your data aren't smooth, so the CIs won't be smooth. Error bars are likely your best choice.

Comment: It won't interpolate `nan` points.